# Finding conditional distribution of a function of a normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $Y$ be a k-variate normal distribution with mean 0, variance  $\sigma^2$

Find conditional distribution of $Y^tY$ given that $a^tY=0$ for some non-zero constant vector $a$.

I know it's expected to show some work when asking for help on homework questions, but I've no idea where to start. Hints in comments appreciated.